# Storing a complex boolean in a variable

Tags: c#

I have a very lengthy boolean variable which looks something like:

`c.Card != null && slot.Card.CardId == c.Card.CardId && slot.E1Number == c.E1Number && slot.Capacity == c.Capacity && slot.PacketLinkCapacity == c.PacketLinkCapacity && slot.TrafficType == c.TrafficType && slot.TxFrequency == c.RxFrequency && slot.RxFrequency == c.TxFrequency && slot.E1Number != null && slot.Capacity != null && slot.ProtectionMode == c.ProtectionMode`

Since this condition needs to be checked frequently I keep writing the same thing over and over again. Is it possible to store this in a variable so I can just reuse that whenever I need?

Comment: what about a method?

Comment: All I can say is you need some refactoring.

Comment: In your complex code is a possible bug: You make some checks for null at the end but in the beginning you already compare them to something else. IMHO it is a good coding style to test for nullity first and afterwards compare it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just create a method that does this check, or if you want to pass that function around, use [`Func<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Func<bool> f = new Func<bool>( () => YourLengthyMethod() );
```

Comment: Either I would make up a anonymous lambda out of it or directly put it into a named method that i can call. But putting the code into a named method that would be wrapped into an anonymous lambda that would be backed into a function object seems a little bit overkill.

Comment: @Oliver: The code is just for completeness, I indeed would use it like you said, but I think the context is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Slot, bool>> Filter(filter)
{
    return cat => [...your code for filtering...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to separate this and write it to another method that you will call it when you want to do all these checks. *It's not good practice to have repeated code in your project.*

For example, in your case, you can give as parameters to this method the info (c.Card, slot.Card.CardId etc) and do the right checking over there.

Answer (score 0):

Smart(ish) usage of C# features:

```
class EvaluatedBoolean
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _evaluation = () => false;

    public EvaluatedBoolean(Func<bool> evaluation)
    {
        _evaluation = evaluation;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(EvaluatedBoolean eb)
    {
        return eb._evaluation.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var eval = new EvaluatedBoolean(() => /*your conditions here*/);
...

PerformSomeWorkIfCondition(eval);

...
void PerformSomeWorkIfCondition(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        //do something
...
```